# How To Test Linq-To-SQL ConnectionString To Make Sure It Is Valid

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql, connection-string

I need to validate the ConnectionString property on a DataContext object to ensure that LINQ can get a connection to the database.  I have tried the two methods below but, they lock up the application if the connection string is invalid.  Is there another way in LINQ to do this?

```
    public static bool TestDBConnection(connectionString)
    {
        bool result = true;
        DomainClassesDataContext db = new DomainClassesDataContext(connectionString);

        try
        {
            // Hangs if connectionString is invalid rather than throw an exception
            db.Connection.Open();

            // Initially, I was just trying to call DatabaseExists but, this hangs as well if the conn string is invalid
            if (!db.DatabaseExists())
            {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = false;
            logger.Fatal(ex.Message);
            logger.Fatal(ex.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Does it really _hang_ or is it just counting down the connection time-out?

Comment: Ah, that is probably it.  I will check that right now...

Comment: The timeout is set to 0 but, I cannot figure out how to change it because there is only a setter on the property.

Comment: It is set by the connection string. `0` is "forever", so there you go :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess I will just use another method for testing the connection string that Linq uses.

Comment: I would still fix the timeout issue though. Eternal connection timeout is not something that makes people happy.

Comment: i couldn't find a way to change the timeout on the linq datacontext so, i decided to use the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection object and it will not allow me to change the timeout either.  do i have to use a loop or timer in the code to deal with that?

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: @Grasshopper set the `Connection Timeout` property in your connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Connection Timeout` in the connection string to a low value like 5s.

Opening is not enough. You might get a stale, pooled connection. Execute a query: `SELECT NULL`.

Comment: That's ultimately what it ended up being.  Another application is generating the connection string that this app is using and it was set to 0 in the connection string.  I ended up having to parse to replace the connection string to 5s and change it on the DataContext.